# Checkout array issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and WP ecommerce, in my checkout my theme is giving me a warning

*Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wpsc_google_checkout_page' not found or invalid function name in /home4/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298*

Here is the line

```
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
```

How do I remedy this?

Comment: Does this help?  Maybe you don't have the latest version?
 https://github.com/wp-e-commerce/WP-e-Commerce/issues/1369

Comment: What is `$the_['function']` holding? Echo or print it so you can confirm it contains what you expect. As of now it must not be a function (or not a valid one), hence the error